# Why the second form not overflow than container?

Tags: html, css

I set `form{with: 60%;}`(two forms) and `section{width: 40%}`(any three are on one line). **So why the second form is not out of `main` container?**

I want the second form not to be displayed. But it should be displayed only after clicking on the link.

```css
body{
  background-image: url("https://s4.uupload.ir/files/7560b48482bfae5c-02b97ffc647f-3822363654_tji3.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
}
main {
  display: flex; /*here*/
  align-items: center;
  width: 50rem;
  overflow: hidden; /*here*/
  border: solid blue;
}
form {
  width: 60%; /*here*/
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
section {
  width: 40%; /*here*/
  padding: 2rem;
  border: solid green;
}
section img {
  width: 16rem;
}
label span {
  color: white;
}
input,button,label span {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <form id="register">
    <label>
         <span>Username</span>
         <img src="./icons/user.svg" alt="" />
         <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Phone</span>
        <img src="./icons/phone.svg" alt="" />
        <input type="tel" />
    </label>
    <button>Register</button>
  </form>
  <section>
    <img src="./illustrations/gangster.svg" alt="" />
  </section>
  <form id="login">
    <label>
        <span>Username</span>
        <img src="./icons/user.svg" alt="" />
        <input type="text" />
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Password</span>
        <img src="./icons/password.svg" alt="" />
        <input type="password" />
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
</main>
```

The current result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Comment: Please make sure your snippet is a [example].

Comment: Working fine, no issue

Comment: @ArifKhan Thanks. Please see two images in my answer. It has an issue in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your register.html page

```
    <main>
       <form id="register">
          <label>
            <span>Username</span>
                    <img src="./icons/user.svg" alt="" />
                     <input type="text" />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Phone</span>
                    <img src="./icons/phone.svg" alt="" />
                    <input type="tel" />
                </label>
                <button>Register</button>
                <p>Already have a account?<a href="login.html">Login Here</a></p>
              </form>
           <section>
            <img src="./illustrations/gangster.svg" alt="" />
          </section>
    </main>
```

Your login.html page

```
<main>
<form id="login">
            <label>
                <span>Username</span>
                <img src="./icons/user.svg" alt="" />
                <input type="text" />
            </label>
            <label>
                <span>Password</span>
                <img src="./icons/password.svg" alt="" />
                <input type="password" />
            </label>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <p>Dont have a account?<a href="register.html">Register Here</a></p>
          </form>
           <section>
            <img src="./illustrations/gangster.svg" alt="" />
          </section>
        </main>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it fixes now. but how to say login's form to be displayed when `login`'s link is clicked? In other words, the register's form be disappear?

Comment: I don't have allowed for the use of javascript.

Comment: wait let me update my answer you can check in 2min

Comment: And why it is not to be overflow? (Since I have 60% - 40% - `60%`)

Comment: because all form is inside main div so it wont go out of the HTML architecture you have to add second form in different div

Comment: Although I can't use jquery. But thanks for your help.

Comment: Ohh sorry , that means you need the solution with only html and css? then the thing is you have to make two html files one for register and second for login and then in the links you can target the other page. Updating my answer